# bash async function

Tags: bash

I have a for loop, within loop, there is while loop, the problem is when the while loop executed, the next for loop never executed.

```
sync[0]='/home/lzyy/tmp,12.34.56.78,test'
sync[1]='/home/lzyy/tmp,23.45.67.89,test'

for item in ${sync[@]}; do

echo $item #only output sync[0]
dir=`echo $item | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
host=`echo $item | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`
module=`echo $item | awk -F"," '{print $3}'`

inotifywait -mrq --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format  '%T %w%f %e' \
 --event CLOSE_WRITE,create,move,delete  $dir | while read  date time file event
    do
        echo 
        # do something, 
    done
done
```

what I can find out to solve this problem is async function, or save the while loop in a separate file, and executed background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `inotifywait ... | while read ...; do ... done` is in fact a single command (single pipeline) in bash, so you can safely add `&` after it to make it run in background. Basically, it would look like that:

```
inotifywait -mrq --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format  '%T %w%f %e' \
 --event CLOSE_WRITE,create,move,delete  $dir | while read  date time file event
    do
        echo 
        # do something, 
    done &
```